# How does this code draw out three circles?

Tags: javascript

I have used this code to improve my original version. It is an automated traffic light that draws out three circles and simulates the Red, Red+Yellow, Green sequence of a British traffic light. The problem is I have no idea how it is drawing out the three circles. I know that the drawLight() draws them but where is the code that tells it where to draw them? Can please explain this to me thanks.

```
<script>   

        var c = document.createElement('canvas'),
        ctx = c.getContext('2d');


    c.width = 150;
    c.height = 300;
    document.body.appendChild(c);

var cycle = 0,
    colours = {
    red: "#cc0000",
    yellow: "#cccc00",
    green: "#00cc00",
    off: "#333333"
    };

function drawLight(id,colour) {
// avoid repetition, use a function!
ctx.fillStyle = colours[colour];
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(95, 50 + 100*id, 40, 0, Math.PI*2);
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();
}

function changelight(){
ctx.stokeStyle = "black";
ctx.lineWidth = 3;

// top light: red if cycle = 0 or 1, off otherwise
drawLight(0, cycle <= 1 ? 'red' : 'off');

// middle light: yellow if cycle = 3 (and 1 for UK lights, we have red+yellow before green), off otherwise
drawLight(1, cycle == 1 || cycle == 3 ? 'yellow' : 'off');

// bottom light: green if cycle = 2
drawLight(2, cycle == 2 ? 'green' : 'off');

// increment cycle
cycle = (cycle + 1) % 4;
}

// start the magic
setInterval(changelight,1000);
</script>

        <br><br>
        <button onclick="changelight()">Click</button>
```

Comment: `setInterval` calls `changelight` every 1 second which calls at its turn `drawLight` three times with different `cycle` values. If `cycle` is 0 it draws the red light, if it's 1 it draws the yellow light and if it's 2 it draws the red light. Then it sets `cycle = (cycle + 1)  % 4` which means that the next value can be 0, 1, 2 or 3. The catch is that the `changelight` draws 1 circle at a time depending of the `cycle` value. Downvoted your question because you didn't show a minimal effort to understand the code.

Answer (score 1):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arc

```
ctx.beginPath();
//       x           y       radius     startAngle,  endAngle
ctx.arc(95,    50 + 100*id,    40,         0,         Math.PI*2);
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();
```

Comment: where does it say draw three?

Comment: `changelight ` calls `drawLight` three times

Comment: Here's the first:
`// top light: red if cycle = 0 or 1, off otherwise`
`drawLight(0, cycle <= 1 ? 'red' : 'off');`

The second:
`// middle light: yellow if cycle = 3 (and 1 for UK lights, we have red+yellow before green), off otherwise`
`drawLight(1, cycle == 1 || cycle == 3 ? 'yellow' : 'off');`

And the third:
`// bottom light: green if cycle = 2`
`drawLight(2, cycle == 2 ? 'green' : 'off');`

The comments are pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: @GigiSan But your comment is not legible

Comment: Sorry, SO crops any newline... :(

Answer (score 0):

Using the HTML5 Canvas Element (http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp). The arc function is used to draw circles. See: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_arc.asp